# how to call a firebase sample cloud function from unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

The sample function that firebae creates is this below. Now i want to call it from unity. added and configured firebase in unity already.

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

now i am not sure that to call a function do i need authentication? if yes how should i call the function?

i used this code to call the function. My function name is testunity and i have posted the code snipped of cloud function above.

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> Start()
    {
        FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.GetInstance(projectId);


        Debug.Log("Calling");
        var function = functions.GetHttpsCallable("testunity");
        return function.CallAsync("helloWorld").ContinueWith((task) => {
            return (string)task.Result.Data;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client is using a callable type function, but your backend is not.  If you want to use a callable function from the client, you will need to implement a callable function on the backend (not an HTTP function has you have now).  See the documentation for details:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Your callable function will look more like this:

```
exports.testunity = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```